# Is there any way to an app in node.js know how much ram has the computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hardware, ram, disk

I am making an application in node.js and I need to know how much ram is installed on the computer **NOT TOTAL USE**. If you know of other ways to find out more about the hardware, like the type of disk and how much space is available and its total, I'd like to hear you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information directly, but you likely would want to rely on a package to simply the task.

You may want to look at [`systeminformation` from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation#4-memory).

- si.mem(...) to get memory information (`total`, for example).
- si.diskLayout(...) for disk information, etc..

Answer (score 1):

The `os` module provides operating system-related utility methods and properties.
You dont need to install it as a package. Its built-in.
Works on any platform.

```
os.cpus()
os.freemem()
os.networkInterfaces()
```

and many more, look into
https://nodejs.org/api/os.html

Comment: Yes I'm using it already, but it does not provide me info about the disk and the total ram installed.